# Passing parameters between modules in Verilog

Tags: verilog, vivado

I am trying to learn how to pass parameters in Verilog.  So far I've learned that the declaration looks like this:

```
module funct #(parameter n = 32)
(input clk, input [n-1:0]in, input reset, input L,
input load, input shift, output reg[n-1:0] out);
```

I instantiate another module within that module that depends on the parameter, so I defined the parameter there as well.

```
module funct2 #(parameter n = 32) (
    input clk,
    input [n-1:0] in,
    input rst,
    input  L,
    output  [n-1:0] out
    );
```

My question is how to call `funct2` within `funct`?

I was also wondering how I can instantiate `funct` within the testbench folder. Without the `parameter`, it looked like this

```
funct uut(.clk(clk),.in(in), .reset(reset),.L(L), .load(load), .shift(shift), .out(out));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax is used to instantiate `funct2` within `funct`, passing the `parameter` into the module:

```
funct2 #(.n(n)) i1 (.clk(clk), .in(in), .rst(reset), .L(L), .out(out));
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.3.2 *Module instantiation syntax*.

The syntax you used to instantiate `funct` inside the testbench is valid, as you've discovered.  The default value of 32 is used in this case.  Optionally, you could use the `#(.n(n))` syntax to explicitly show that you are passing a parameter.